# How to add multiple attribute/parameters in ASP.NET Core MVC tag helper syntax?

Tags: url, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

Here’s how the filtering should work:

- On initial load, or when the user clicks the All FAQs link, the app should display all the FAQs.
- When the user clicks a category link, the app should filter FAQs by category. If the user subsequently clicks a topic link, the FAQs will be filtered by topic and by category.
- When the user clicks a topic link, the app should filter FAQs by topic. If the user subsequently clicks a category link, the app should filter the FAQs by topic and by category.

This is my requirement, need to create url like

```
http://localhost/home/index/topic/javascript
```

but I don't know how to build such url using asp attributes in view on the basis of filters selected.

I have tried this one

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark"   
   href = "@Url.Action("FAQs", new { category = "Technical", topic = "Installation" })">JavaScript</a>
```

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" 
   asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Bootstrap</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how to build such url using asp attributes in view on the basis of filters selected

In [asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions?view=aspnetcore-7.0) you would have seen [UrlHelperExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions?view=aspnetcore-7.0) class which has extesion class methos of [Url.Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-urlhelperextensions-action(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-iurlhelper-system-string-system-string-system-object)) and [Url.RouteUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.routeurl?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-urlhelperextensions-routeurl(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-iurlhelper-system-string-system-object-system-string-system-string)) that would seen as following:

[image]

[image]

> How to add multiple attribute/parameters in ASP.NET Core MVC tag
> helper syntax?

Using [Url.Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-urlhelperextensions-action(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-iurlhelper-system-string-system-string-system-object)) and [Url.RouteUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.routeurl?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-urlhelperextensions-routeurl(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-iurlhelper-system-string-system-object-system-string-system-string)) TagHelper method which has overloaded parameter type of [object? values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.routeurl?view=aspnetcore-7.0#overloads) where you could pass your multiple attribute/parameters to your controller as per your needs.

**Solution:**

Let's check that in practice:

Controller:

```
public class HtmlTagHelperController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult DoubleParamter(string? category, string? topic)
        {
            var response = string.Format("You have sent: Category:{0}, Topic:{1}", category, topic);
            return Ok(response);
        }
        public ActionResult TripleParamter(string? category, string? topic, int? page)
        {
            var response = string.Format("You have sent: Category:{0}, Topic:{1}, Page: {2}", category, topic, page);
            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
```

Razor Tag Helper:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="@Url.Action("DoubleParamter","HtmlTagHelper", new { category="Technical",topic="Instalattion"})">Way: 1 : Submit Double Parameter</a>
<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="@Url.RouteUrl("default", new{httproute = "", controller="HtmlTagHelper",action="DoubleParamter",category="Technical",topic="Instalattion"})">Way: 2 : Submit Double Parameter</a>
<hr />


<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="@Url.Action("TripleParamter","HtmlTagHelper", new { page=1,category="Technical",topic="Instalattion"})">Way: 1 :Submit Triple Parameter</a>
<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="@Url.RouteUrl("default", new{httproute = "", controller="HtmlTagHelper",action="TripleParamter",category="Technical",topic="Instalattion",page=1})">Way: 2 :Submit Triple Parameter</a>
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [asp.net core TagHelperExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions?view=aspnetcore-7.0) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions?view=aspnetcore-7.0).